# How to output an function within HTML with vbscript

Tags: html, vbscript

I have a html list which i want to dynamicly enable or disabled based on input. Usually at the end of the select you just use enabled or disabled to disable or enable the whole html list. But im not sure how to use function to do this.

```
       <select size="5" name="name" onChange="rolevalue" enabler()>
            <option value="1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>  
        </p>
        </select>
```

Here is my function

```
Function enabler()
    if ListboxCustomer.value = 1 Then
        document.write "enabled"
    else
        document.write "disabled"
    end if
End Function
```

I know ListboxCustomer.value is set to 1 but the function isnt used. I know in C# i need to return my function for it to do anything, but ive read many examples of functions in vbscript and they dont use that.  Any help? :)

Comment: Why are you trying to write client side VBScript? It is only supported by Internet Explorer (and IE 11 only supports it in "compatibility mode").

Comment: Its in a HTA file which i use for System Center. I need to disable a HTML list based on an if condition in my function. Basicly if someone have choosen option 1, then disable the entire list :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If your doing this in a HTA use the following

```
<select size="5" name="name" onchange="enabler()">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>  
</select>
```

Then define your event handler

```vb
Sub enabler()
    Set List = window.event.srcElement
    List.Enabled = Not (List.Value = 1)
End Sub
```

---

For context this is purely a solution for the OPs specific requirement. I wouldn't recommend this approach normally. It's worth remember you can still use JavaScript in a HTA Application, but the OP specifically asked about using VBScript.

Comment: So the down-vote is for what exactly? Does the solution not work?

Comment: Ok it's not elegant, but for a scenario where someone is using MSHTA with VBScript it works.